# Mysql ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint state_id

Tags: mysql

I am currently attempting to learn mysql and I am on the section of referencing foreign keys but cannot seem to get it to accept it.
What am I missing? Hope you can help :)

```
mysql> create table states (
    -> id tinyint(3) not null primary key auto_increment,
    -> name varchar(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create table customers (
    -> id integer(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> name varchar(255) not null,
    -> email varchar(255) not null,
    -> states_id tinyint unsigned not null,
    -> foreign key(states_id) references states(id) on update cascade);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Hi, I just resolved this the same way! thanks for the input :)

mysql> create table customers (
    -> id integer(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> name varchar(255) not null,
    -> email varchar(255) not null,
    -> states_id tinyint(3) not null,
    -> foreign key(states_id) references states (id) on update cascade);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

Answer (score 2):

Columns related through foreign keys need to have the same data type.  The id is TINYTINT(3) but states_id is TINYTINT UNSIGNED.

Redefine your definition of states and try it again.

Comment: Many thanks! Just got it there I cannot believe I missed this, I noticed it just after I read my post.